# Facebook E-Com& Subscription Model

Tags: facebook, e-commerce

I've Google.  I've Binged.  I've posted on **both** the Facebook dev boards, as well as Payvment's discussion forum, and no one seems to be able to answer what I thought was a very simple, straight-forward question. So I figured it couldn't hurt to take my chances in here.

I am writing a Facebook app which will be performing a real-world service for the user. I would like it to implement a subscription-based model, where the user pays $x/month to use the service (the app).

So I hear about this thing called the Facebook **Credits API**, and it seems like it's exactly what I'm looking for. Facebook handles all the nasty ecom/PCI compliance stuff, users buy tokens for your app, you get the money, and then your biz logic hits the API to see if the user has sufficient credits to use your app. Sadly, I was mistaken.

According to their Credit Integration Guide, it seems like Facebook credits are only good for game tokens and virtual goods. Not for real-world products. But then I heard about Payvment...

Payvment is this new ecom platform for managing real-world storefronts on Facebook.  Free public beta even, into perpetuity.

But, for the life of me, I can't seem to get an answer to this question: **can one use Payvment to charge users for services, not physical products?** If not, what Facebook integration (if any) exists to provide for such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Payvment uses PayPal for checkouts inside Facebook.

As you are writing a Facebook App, you are able to use any 3rd party payment solution within your canvas, even PayPal.